# how can put image inside the image in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5mLQ.png

Like what we see a small circular image inside the big picture . And how to arrange the text as in the picture

https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5mLQ.png

Comment: This site works best if you present a problem and show what you have tried (as text) and share the results. See [ask]. You probably aren't going to get much traction just asking for code examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Container(
    height: 150.0,
    margin: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
    decoration: new BoxDecoration(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(new Radius.circular(10.0)),
        gradient: new LinearGradient(colors: [Colors.yellow[700], Colors.redAccent],
            begin: Alignment.centerLeft, end: Alignment.centerRight, tileMode: TileMode.clamp)),
    child: new Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
          child: new CircleAvatar(radius: 35.0, backgroundImage: NetworkImage('https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp2365076.jpg'),)
        ),
        new Expanded(child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Text('New York', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.white70, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
            new SizedBox(height: 8.0,),
            new Text('Sunny', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0, color: Colors.white70),),
            new SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
            new Row(children: <Widget>[
              new Column(children: <Widget>[
                new Text('2342', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0, color: Colors.white)),
                new Text('Popularity', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 10.0, color: Colors.white)),
              ],),
              new Column(children: <Widget>[
                new Text('2342', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0, color: Colors.white)),
                new Text('Like', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 10.0, color: Colors.white)),
              ],),
              new Column(children: <Widget>[
                new Text('2342', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0, color: Colors.white)),
                new Text('Followed', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 10.0, color: Colors.white)),
              ],)
            ],)
          ],)),
        new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
          child: new Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
            new Text('12°', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0, color: Colors.white70),),
            new Text('Ranking', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0, color: Colors.white70),),
          ],))

      ],),
  );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It will take a few widgets to accomplish what you would like to achieve. Here is how I would solve it (it might need some fine tuning to fit your exact needs, but should get you started):

First start with the background (I believe you call it the big picture). To accomplish this you could use the `Container` widget to draw the rectangle and use set the `decoration` property with a `BoxDecoration` widget to set the background image.

Next set the `child` property of the `Container` widget with a `Row` widget which will contain the circular image and a `Column` widget to contain the text elements.

The whole thing could look something like this:

```
new Container(
    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
        image: new DecorationImage(
            image: new AssetImage('assets/images/card_background.png'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
    ),
    child: new Row(
        children: <Widget>[
            new CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: new AssetImage('assets/images/avatar.png')
            ),
            new Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                    new Text('David Borg'),
                    new Text('Title: Flying Wing'),
                ],
            ),
        ],
    ),
)
```

Here are some references to the most important widgets used in the above code snippet:

- [Container](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html) widget
- [BoxDecoration](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/BoxDecoration-class.html) widget
- [CircleAvatar](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/CircleAvatar-class.html) widget
- [Column](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html) widget
- [Row](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html) widget

Note that I have not tested the code listed in the snippet so it might need a little bit of tweaking.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this example (a hamburger icon and three red points over a purple clipped background):

[image: Hamburger icon over purple background]

If you would like to have this, the code would be pretty short:

```
body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          ClipPath(
            clipper: MyClipper(),
            child: Container(
              height: 350,
              width: double.infinity,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
                  Color.fromRGBO(16, 27, 117, 0.5),
                  Color.fromRGBO(16, 27, 117, 0.5),
                ]),
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage(
                    "assets/images/points_removed.png",
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment(-0.8, -0.6),
                child: Image.asset(
                  "assets/images/hamburger_icon.png",
                  width: 30,
                  height: 20,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

(optional) the code for clipping the background

```
class MyClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    var path = Path();
    path.lineTo(0, size.height - 80);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
        size.width / 2, size.height, size.width, size.height - 80);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: If you wish to open the drawer with the hamburger icon have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55547041/11322237) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55700267/11322237).