# Flutter - Is there a way to use just IconButton (without creating an app bar) to open the drawer?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to use the IconButton that can open the drawer on my app page, so when I tap the icon button, I expect to see the drawer. I've been looking up a way to do so online, but seemed like there're only two solutions: I can either use the appbar to put the IconButton in, or I can try the floating action button. But they're not what I'm looking for, I want just the IconButton to open the drawer. Is it possible do it?

Comment: take a look on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47435231/change-the-menu-icon-for-drawer-at-appbar . I already have the same problem and this answer helps me

Comment: @RubensMelo the problem is the IconButton is still in appBar. I want to use the IconButton to open the drawer, but I really don't want an app bar in my page.

Comment: the solution is the same, use a globally to "active" drawer with icon button using `_scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the menu icon for drawer at appbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47435231/change-the-menu-icon-for-drawer-at-appbar)

Comment: Figured this out. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can easily open the drawer through **IconButton** without using **appBar**.
You need to use Key like I had used _scaffoldKey and use **_scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer()** method to open the drawer in **IconButton** widget.

```
class HomeState extends StatelessWidget {

final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey =  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

 @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return Scaffold(
  key: _scaffoldKey,
         drawer: Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          ListTile(
            title: Text("Ttem 1"),
            trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: Text("Item 2"),
            trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
        body: ListView(
         children:[

    Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0,top:100.0),
              child: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
                onPressed: () {
                  _scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer();
                },

              ),
            ),
            ]
        ),
            );}


   }
```